# Powershell script - Change IP using the InterfaceDescription

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script that changes a single port on a computer.

I have 10 machines, each have 4 ports with one port out the four having a specific Interface Description "Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection". This is constant throughout all the machines. The other 3 ports are just “Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection” ports.

I only care for the 82579LM port. I want a script that will set a static IP to this one interface that I can run on each machine after a reinstall. I already have a script that is able to use the hostname to set the IP but I cannot figure a way to change the IP using the Interface Description from get-netadapter to select the adapter.

I can't get my head around this, any input would be amazing!

Comment: Hello :) Welcome! Clould you please show code with what you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick/easy method would be to hold the object from your Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription results in a variable

```
PS> $INTEL82579LM=Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"
```

You can access individual attributes of the object as $variable.attribute -- so the interface ID is $INTEL82579LM.ifIndex

```
PS> echo $INTEL82579LM.ifIndex
19
```

The object held in the variable is used to insert the interface index number on subsequent commands:

```
PS>Set-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $INTEL82579LM.ifIndex -IPAddress 10.1.2.3 -PrefixLength 24
```

[Set-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-netipaddress?view=win10-ps) is for updating existing IP address config. [New-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/new-netipaddress?view=win10-ps) creates a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this solved my issue (I'm not the best at powershell scripting). Script:

Comment: 'param (
    [string]$ethernetAdapterName = $env:ethernetAdapterName, 
    [string]$capturedIP = $env:capturedIP,
    [string]$capturedGateway = $env:capturedGateway
)

Write-Host "Changing adapter: " $ethernetAdapterName 
Write-Host "IP:" $capturedIP " Gateway:" $capturedGateway
$INTEL82579LM=Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription $ethernetAdapterName
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $INTEL82579LM.ifIndex -IPAddress $capturedIP -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $capturedGateway'